# Update a item from a list width Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

I've started using Backbone.js and i have an issue  with the updating of html elements.
This is my code:

Router:

```
App.Routers.Test = Backbone.Router.extend({  

    routes: {  
        "/start" :      "start",
        "/modify" :     "modify"
    }, 

    start: function() {  

        this.List = new App.Collections.Test;
        this.ViewList = new App.Views.Test({model: this.List});

        this.List.fetch();

    },

    modify: function() {  
        var model = this.List.get(1);
        model.set({name: 'Item modified'});
        alert('Modified!');
    } 

});
```

Views:

```
App.Views.Item = Backbone.View.extend({

    inizialize: function() {
        this.model.bind('change:name',this.render);
    },

    render: function() {
        $('#tmpl').tmpl(this.model.attributes).appendTo(this.el);   // jQuery Template
        return this;
    }

});

App.Views.Test = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '#list',

    initialize: function() {                            
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');          
        this.model.bind('reset', this.render);          
    },

    render: function() {
        $(this.el).empty();
        this.model.each(function(model) {
            var viewItem = new App.Views.Item({model: model});
            $('#list').append((viewItem.render().el));
        });     
    }



});
```

When I go to "#/modify" the Model has changed, but this not updated on  the html view, although I have added in the item views this code:

```
this.model.bind('change:name',this.render);
```

Maybe I didn't understand the correct functioning of backbone, how to behave?

PS: Since I'm new on  backbone, is accept any advice.

Answer (score 0):

In your `modify` method, call the appropriate view. I usually pass an instance of the `model` and `el`. So, for example:

```
this.modifyPage = new App.Views.Test({
    el: $('#list'),
    model: model
});
```

Though, if you don't need the `el` as context from the router, it's best to limit the use of jQuery to only the views.